# Is there a linguistic term for omitting the last syllable of a word and joining it with the next, in speech?

Tags: regionalismo, fenômeno-linguístico

In certain parts of Brazil (in the rural areas of Minas Gerais, for instance) some people tend to omit the last syllable of a word and join two words in speech. Is there a term for this linguistic phenomenon?

examples:

- O bolo tá **dendoforno** (dentro do forno)
- Eu já fiz **metádoserviço** (metade do serviço)
- Eu **tenquifazê** um monte de coisas hoje (tenho que fazer)

Comment: O nome é dialeto, porém é conhecido culturalmente no brasil como sotaque regional. Leia sobre sotaques e dialetos: 
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialeto e  https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialeto_mineiro e https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialeto_nordestino

Comment: @StriterAlfa "dialect" is a broad term which encompasses pronunciation, vocabulary, idioms, and specific elements of culture. My question is about a linguistic term for omitting a syllable and joining words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, this would be a type of *[elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision)*:

> the omission of one or more sounds (such as a vowel, a consonant, or a whole syllable) in a word or phrase.

This is a very general term, as you can see from the definition. A more specific term would be *[synalepha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synalepha)*:

> the merging of two syllables into one, especially when it causes two words to be pronounced as one.
>
> … most often refers to elision, …

And one could say that your examples come from [*relaxed pronunciation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxed_pronunciation):

> a phenomenon that happens when the syllables of common words are slurred together.

That page gives Portuguese examples, one of which reminds me of your examples above:

> - *'vambora = vamos embora*

Comment: A good article (in Portuguese) about elision can be found [here](http://sualingua.com.br/2012/06/23/antes-do-ano-terminar/)